# Oracle how to defragment tablespace

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to de-fragment a table space in order to shrink it.

I need the SQL query to find the last element in the table space.

I'm using the following query, but I'm not sure that it is correct:

```
select * from (
    select * from dba_extents where tablespace_name = 'TS_DATA' order by BLOCK_ID desc) 
where rownum<22;
```

I then want to de-fragment it with commands like `alter index XXX_PK rebuild;` and `alter table XXX move;`

My question is: do I have to sort by BLOCK_ID or by EXTENT_ID, or both or other?

I think I must be doing it wrong, since the shrink command doesn't work: `ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE 'C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\TS_DATA.DBF' RESIZE 8777M;`. It can't work because of `ORA-03297: file contains used data beyond requested RESIZE value`.